# Would you say "reading books "is" or "are""

Tags: word-usage, verbs

This is the sentence where it's used: "First of all reading books are important because it develops the mind."

Comment: _Reading books_ is what _it_ means, and that's singular. What do you think?

Comment: But this sentence is also a possible correction depending on intent and interpretation: “Reading books are important because they develop the mind.”

Answer (score 1):

In this case "reading books" is actually short-hand for "the act of reading books". If you substitute that into the given sentence, it's clear that you should use "is" rather than "are" as "the act" is singlular. As noted in the comments on the question, the use of "it" is also a clue.

> First of all, [the act of] reading books is important because it develops the mind.